# how to re-combine a color image separated CMYB in XAML

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I would like to re-combine a color image separated into Cyan / Magenta / Yellow / Black parts into an Windows 10 IOT Application using XAML written in C#..

This is easy in css (see demo https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/).

How do I do this in XAML?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a `UserControl`, here I created a control named "SeparateLetterControl".

XAML code:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Orientation="{x:Bind LetterOritation}" />
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```cs
public sealed partial class SeparateLetterControl : UserControl
{
    private char[] Letterlist;

    private Color[] ColorList;

    public SeparateLetterControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += SeparateLetterControl_Loaded;
    }

    private void SeparateLetterControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Letterlist = WordToArray(OriginalText);
        var LetterstringColorArray = LetterColors.Split(',');
        int colorcount = 0;
        ColorList = new Color[LetterstringColorArray.Count()];
        foreach (var color in LetterstringColorArray)
        {
            ColorList[colorcount] = ConvertToColor(color);
            colorcount++;
        }
        int count = 0;
        if (LetterOritation == Orientation.Horizontal)
        {
            foreach (var i in Letterlist)
            {
                TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
                tb.Text = i.ToString();
                tb.FontSize = 30;
                tb.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, LetterSpacing, 0);
                tb.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(ColorList[count % ColorList.Count()]);
                stackPanel.Children.Add(tb);
                count++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var i in Letterlist)
            {
                TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
                tb.Text = i.ToString();
                tb.FontSize = 30;
                tb.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, LetterSpacing);
                tb.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(ColorList[count % ColorList.Count()]);
                stackPanel.Children.Add(tb);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    //change original word to string[]
    private char[] WordToArray(string originalword)
    {
        return originalword.ToCharArray();
    }

    //convert string to color
    public static Color ConvertToColor(string colorName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(colorName)) throw new ArgumentNullException("colorName");
        MethodBase getColorMethod = FindGetColorMethod(colorName);
        if (getColorMethod == null)
        {
            // Using FormatException like the WPF System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter
            throw new FormatException(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Color name {0} not found in {1}",
                colorName, typeof(Colors).FullName));
        }
        return (Color)getColorMethod.Invoke(null, null);
    }

    private static MethodBase FindGetColorMethod(string colorName)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in typeof(Colors).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties)
        {
            if (propertyInfo.Name.Equals(colorName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                MethodBase getMethod = propertyInfo.GetMethod;
                if (getMethod.IsPublic && getMethod.IsStatic)
                    return getMethod;
                break;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("OriginalText", typeof(string), typeof(SeparateLetterControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string OriginalText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LetterSpacingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LetterSpacing", typeof(int), typeof(SeparateLetterControl), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public int LetterSpacing
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(LetterSpacingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LetterSpacingProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LetterOritationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LetterOritation", typeof(Orientation), typeof(SeparateLetterControl), new PropertyMetadata(Orientation.Horizontal));

    public Orientation LetterOritation
    {
        get { return (Orientation)GetValue(LetterOritationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LetterOritationProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LetterSizeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LetterSize", typeof(double), typeof(SeparateLetterControl), new PropertyMetadata(15));

    public double LetterSize
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(LetterSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LetterSizeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LetterColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LetterColors", typeof(string), typeof(SeparateLetterControl), new PropertyMetadata("Black"));

    public string LetterColors
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LetterColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LetterColorProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Now you can use it for example in you MainPage.XAML like this:

```
<local:SeparateLetterControl OriginalText="Hello, World!" LetterOritation="Horizontal" LetterSpacing="-10" LetterSize="50"
                             LetterColors="Cyan,Magenta,Yellow,Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

Now you will see the rendering image:

[image]

Please notice that I exposed four properties of this control, they are "OriginalText", "LetterSpacing", "LetterOritation", "LetterSize" and "LetterColors".

You can set the text to the property `OriginalText`, the `LetterSpacing` property  is the space between each letter, the `LetterOritation` can be set to "Horizontal" or "Vertical", the `LetterSize` represents the `FontSize` of each letter, and `LetterColors`.

**[Important!]**
By now the `LetterColors` property's type is string, and the format of this property should be like "Color,Color,Color", you can define any color you want and any number of colors you like, but please right spell the color's name and don's use any symbol except "," in this property, I didn't handle these exceptions, even a white space can cause the error here.

Comment: I didn't expose the FontFamily property here, anyway, you can refer to my code upper to complete this work.